# Do peripherals (Keyboard/Mouse) still get identified correctly after going through a KVM switch?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse, kvm-switch

I'm considering trying a simple KVM switch to use a single keyboard and mouse to control two machines. I've read that these don't need need drivers, but I'm curious to know if the signal from the mouse and keyboard is altered in any way?

For instance, if I'm using a certain Logitech mouse with it's drivers, will it still get identified as the same mouse after going through the KVM or will it appear as a generic mouse input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. A simple KVM switch **without USB enumeration** give you full access to your USB device. But if you switch, for your computer, it works is like disconnect/connect your input devices. A better KVM switch **with USB enumeration** typically simulate your devices by type. So, for example, all computers think the generic mouse is still connected.

So, if you like to use all mouse features, you should look for a KVM switch without USB enumeration or an excellent KVM switch with *full* USB enumeration. For this, you have to read the technical specifications.